# Jinja: Check if variable is iterable

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Is there a way in Jinja to check if a variable is iterable? I'm working with Django and depening on whether I use `objects.filter` or `objects.get` the `response` is send to the jinja template is could be iterable or not.

I tried the following:

```
{% extends 'header.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if response is iterable %}
    {% for i in response %}
        <p>i</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
     {{ response }}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, Django throws: `Unused 'is' at end of if expression.`

Comment: Why not always just send a list?

Comment: @IanAuld Because I find using `objects.get` easier to use in my scenario. It would be possible to always send a list, however I thought Jinja would be capable of checking?

Comment: Sending a list would be cleaner.  If you use `objects.get` just put it into a list by itself before sending to the template.

Comment: You can put one item in a list

Comment: @Plasma Well, in my case when dealing with a single object, I'd like to put it in <h3> tags, when dealing with a list, I'd like to use <li>. Jinja says in the docs `iterable` checks if you can iterate, so it must be possible?

Comment: Either way, it looks like your syntax is wrong. Should probably be `{% if iterable response %}` according to a quick glancing over of the docs.

Comment: It works for me:
`{% if value is iterable %}`

Documentation [here:](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#iterable)

Answer (score 4):

The above answer no longer works for me, however the below does:

`{% if response is iterable %}`

One caveat with this though is that it would deem a string iterable (which it is) and would then loop over every letter in the string, a more appropriate check might be:

`{% if response is iterable and response is not string %}`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`{% if iterable(response) %}`

Comment: Doesn't work either, sadly: `Could not parse the remainder: '(response)' from 'iterable(response)'`

Comment: Without the parens maybe? `if iterable response`